# how to show all children in a recyclerview (FirebaseRecyclerOptions) for a specific user

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

[new database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HKma.png)

This is how I show data for each user using FirebaseRecyclerOptions.

But I want to get all children data for only a specific user with a condition by checking users with UID or any other solution.

Ps : This post was edited many times because of the database structure has been changed

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdv, container, false);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.pdv_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
      
     
           
        if (user_id.equals("hZBCb9yk8ycamjoVcISjG2y4ZnI2")){
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://dtechapp-94795-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")
                .getReference().child("commande").orderByChild("user_id").equalTo("hZBCb9yk8ycamjoVcISjG2y4ZnI2"); ;

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Order> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Order>()
                        .setQuery(query, Order.class)
                        .build();


        pdvAdapter = new PdvAdapter(options);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(pdvAdapter);
        return v;
       }
}
```

Comment: what you are getting currently?

Comment: it doesn't work.... What do u mean by zonesRef ? is it rootRef ? By the way user_id is a string ---- String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()

Comment: Updated answer please check it.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: i don't get any data its clear

Comment: Can please send your snapshot?

Comment: i update the post. this is what I'am using please check it

Comment: I don't know if u understand me but i want to show (Amine) and (Zouoaui...) ""from picture ahead"" at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you using the following query:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://dtechapp-94795-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")
            .getReference("pdv").child("user_id");
```

It means that you are trying to read data from:

```
rootRef/pdv/user_id
```

Such a reference actually **doesn't** exist. Under your "pdv" node there is **no** child called "user_id", but one called "fP0LLs83MYZqX9BqYO24IX80F3Q2". So you either use:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://dtechapp-94795-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")
            .getReference("pdv").child("fP0LLs83MYZqX9BqYO24IX80F3Q2");
```

Or if that UID of the user that comes from a Firebase authentication operation, you can then simply use:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://dtechapp-94795-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app")
            .getReference("pdv").child(uid);
```

**Edit:**

According to one of your comments:

> So I want to get data from children of all users at the same time. This is 1st user "fP0LLs83MYZqX9BqYO24IX80F3Q2" I want to get children inside him and at the same time, I want to get children from 2nd user "hZBCb9yk8ycamjoVcISjG2y4ZnI2" and display it in my RecyclerView.

And according to your [database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gygoq.png), please note that you cannot achieve that. There is no way you can get all users having such a schema. Queries in the Realtime Database work on a flat list of nodes. Besides that, you have an unknown key under the UID node, which makes it impossible to query. To solve this, you should consider removing one level in your tree, and add "Amine" and "Zouaoui..." as properties inside each UID node. Your schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- pvd
       |
       --- $uid
       |     |
       |     --- type: "Amine..."
       |     |
       |     --- //Other fields.
       |
       --- $uid
             |
             --- type: "Zouaoui..."
             |
             --- //Other fields.
```

The code may remain unchanged.

Comment: thanks but this is not what i'am looking for ( i use it in else below the if condition ). What I am looking for is to show children of both of users which means "Amine" and "Zouaoui..."

Comment: In that case, you should another `.child()` call like this `.child("Amine")`. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: have u understand what i want exactly ?!

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so I can further help. What exactly didn't work? Or maybe explain to me again, so I can understand better.

Comment: it means nothing display in my app. So I want to get data from children of all users at the same time. This is 1st user "fP0LLs83MYZqX9BqYO24IX80F3Q2" i want to get children inside him and at the same time i want to get children from 2nd user "hZBCb9yk8ycamjoVcISjG2y4ZnI2" and display it in my recyclerview. is it okay !!

Comment: I understood. Please edit your question and show us the content of "Amine" and "Zouaoui...".

Comment: I did it. I am waiting for ur answer, Thank you

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: sorry but I didn't fix the problem yet.

Comment: Have you tried my solution from my edited answer? Is there any problem with that?

Comment: Look I update the post can u check it now

Comment: I changed the structure of my database, Can I get specific "pdv" by get the "user_id" ?? You should know that a user can create many "pdv" not only one so I attribute user_id for every "pdv" created by the user !! is it possible ?

Comment: Your new database schema looks good to me. To make it work, please change `Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://dtechapp-94795-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference().child("pdv");` into `Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://dtechapp-94795-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").getReference().child("pdv").orderByChild("user_id").equalTo("hzBC...");`.

Comment: In this way, you'll be able to get all children of a single user. Does it work now?

Comment: Hey, can u check this please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69721658/how-get-item-details-from-firebase-in-a-new-activity-by-onclick-in-firebaserecyc